# sudo is broken in my Ubuntu 14.04 server VM in Xenserver

Tags: virtual-machine, sudo, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server

**sudo** does not work in my Ubuntu 14.04 server VM in Xenserver. I guess it is broken. I forgot the password of root user and am not able to log in to it. Since it is a VM in XenServer, reboot is not showing me the grub. How can I fix the problem.

This is the error that I get while using sudo:-

```
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 1 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Additional info:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/sudo

-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 155008 Aug 28  2015 /usr/bin/sudo

ls -l /etc/sudoers

-r--r----- 1 root root 4 Mar  1 11:31 /etc/sudoers
```

Thanks

Comment: Mount the root disk on another VM and change the `/etc/passwd` file from there. Don't know the details on Xenserver, but the process should work.

Comment: As far as I know the passwords are saved encrypted in the /etc/shadow file (except for old Linux distributions) , so you would need to change the shadow and passwd file and enrypt the password yourself to change the password.

Comment: But then to get into the shadow file i need permission, which I don't have

Comment: This was just hypothetical, see my answers below which is much more practical. Also note that you do not need the permission of your faulted system if you simply boot from another system were you have root access, from there you can than change any file on your other systems partition as long as it's not encrypted

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about xen but with VirtualBox you could just add a Linux live iso and 
set the boot priority higher than the virtual hdd. You should then be able to boot into the live Linux and access the virtual hdd, mount your root partition with

```
sudo mount /dev/sdxx /mountpoint
```

Or automount. then navigate to `/etc/sudoers` and fix the wrong line.

> sudo vim /mountpoint/etc/sudoers

Or nano or whatever Texteditor you prefer.

If you have a second vm you can do the above there just add the virtual hdd to the second vm with a lower boot priority.

Comment: This is where I would start

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help.
I just solved my problem.

Since it was a VM in XenServer I was not able to get into the grub just by pressing shift. After searching for sometime I found a way to get into the root user. 
What I did is:

I Right clicked on the problematic VM -> Properties,

then went to the Boot Options tab. I modified OS Boot Parameters from:

**-- quiet console=hvc0**

to:

**single**

Then after a reboot, I could drop directly to the root shell prompt.
My 1st priority was to change root password. Changing password of a user by first logging into it does not require old password. I just used the command **passwd** and the VM aked me for my new password.

Then I changed the Boot Parameters of the VM to -- quiet console=hvc0 and did a reboot.

I had already cloned the VM into another server. But since this VM is a live server, I had to recover from the problem.
I ssh'ed the sudoers file from the clone to another folder in the live server using the root privilege since there was some error in directly copying the file. Then is copied the file to the sudoers file in the live VM and voila!!